# Accurately measure the distance from chest to back

Tags: sensors

I want to measure the distance between the back of a human body, and the chest. This is denoted in the image below, where Point A is the back and Point B is the chest:

[image]

I do not wish to measure the diameter of the chest. Rather, the direct path from Point A, to Point B ( Through the Ribcage ). Do any **mobile sensors** exist that can help me capture this data, which can be worn by the applicant at all times? ( During sleep, walking, running, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest answer would be "a large pair of calipers". In fact, they make such a tool for exactly this task. See http://www.seritex.com/gpm-large-spreading-caliper-rounded-ends-108/

> The GPM Large Spreading Caliper with rounded ends provides accurate
>   measurement of the distance between two points, where one or both
>   points may not be on a flat surface. This Large Spreading Caliper can
>   also be used for the measurement of Anterior-Posterior chest depth.
>
> The ends of the spreading branches are rounded for the patient's
>   comfort, as opposed to the GPM Large Spreading Caliper model 109,
>   which has pointed ends.
>
> The GPM Large Spreading Caliper with rounded ends is manufactured from
>   chrome plated steel. Hinged at the base, the two curved branches with
>   rounded ends are connected by a pivotal ruler, which is engraved in
>   millimeter intervals from 0 to 60 cm. The branches can be immobilized
>   in any position by a screw located on the slider which guides the
>   ruler. The ruler gives the precise distance between the two points
>   over which the measurement has been taken.

Or you could improvise by using something like this:

[image]

NOTE: The OP changed the question to include the "mobile and wearable" requirements, after this answer was written.

Comment: Not sure I see how this is a sensor?

Comment: All you need is a sensor that detects the position ie opening of the caliper arms and you have a solution.

Comment: I am looking for sensors that can be placed on the chest and the back to measure distance through the ribcage. A huge caliper is a no-go.

Comment: @angryip Clairifying the question is perfectly fine.  Expecting that everyone will connect all the dots for you is a bit much.

Comment: The reason I phrased my original question with just sensors was that I inferred mobility. The answer did not, hence why I updated it.

Comment: I have edited and / or removed a number of comments on this post to bring the commentary in line with StackExchange's "Be Nice" policy.